# Why does the uniform probability function have the y value it does? (1/b-a)

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions

It seems very clear in the discrete case.  Rolling a die for example, you have a discrete valued function $f(x)= \frac{1}{6}$, $x \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. The sum of all the values is 1.

In the continuous case, you still want the area under the curve to be 1, so it makes sense that if you are taking $a\le x \le b$, you get $f(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}$.

But... if you imagine the transition from the discrete case to the continuous case, you would get $$f(x)=\frac{1}{n}, x\in\{1,...,n\}$$

So here, given the behavior of this step function as $n$ grows, it feels like for the continuous case, *regardless* of the distance $b-a$, the value of $f(x)$ should always equal zero (i.e. the limit of $\frac{1}{n}$ as $n$ grows without bound).

(Which seems to correctly reflect the idea that the probability of any specific random real draw from some interval is said to be zero.)

So the area-under-the-curve intuition suggests a value of $\frac{1}{b-a}$, the transition-from-discrete-case intuition suggest a value of zero.

(Which is in line with that saying about the reals, which makes sense to me but which I don't know the origin of.)

How/why is it that these competing intuitions are resolved in favor of $\frac{1}{b-a}$?

Comment: The density function $f(x)$ at $x$ is not a probability, the probability we are between $x$ and $x+\Delta x$ is approximately $f(x)(\Delta x)$.

Comment: Perhaps it would be more helpful to think of a transition from the continuous to the discrete. For the discrete case for $x \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, we can start with a continuous range $0 \leq x < n$, then take $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thank-you.  I think that did the trick for me.

Comment: Saty, Théophile ... thanks.  I will have to ponder those a bit.

Comment: Alternatively, consider what is $P(a< X< a+t(b-a))$ as a function of $t$ and then preform a limit process

Comment: You are welcome. We can imagine a large number $n$ of points, each with weight $1/n$. The number of points between $x$ and $x+\Delta x$ is approximately $\frac{\Delta x}{b-a} n$. Multiply by the weight (probability) $1/n$ of each, and we get $\frac{\Delta x}{b-a}$.